# add mousewheel eventlistener error

Tags: javascript, function, events, addeventlistener, mousewheel

Here is the problem :

i have a function, which should return nothing... it is called :

```
function zoom(event){
    alert("wheel delta : "+event.wheelDelta);
    return false;
}
```

on click on my element, i try to add an event listener on mousewheel this way :

```
element.addEventListener("mousewheel",zoom,false);
```

element is a svg tag. but, function zoom is never called, i only get this message back :

```
TypeError: Argument 2 of EventTarget.addEventListener is not an object.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help :)

EDIT : here is the whole code :

```
function ZoomMain(){
var zoom = 0;
var main;
var clicks = 0;
this.click = function(event,svg){
    if(svg){
        switch(clicks%2){
            case 0 :
                main = svg;
                main.addEventListener("mousewheel",zoom,false);
                clicks++;
            break;
            case 1 :
                main.removeEventListener("mousewheel",zoom,false);
                clicks++;
            break;
        }
    }else{
        alert("ERROR");
    }
};

function zoom(event){
    alert("wheel delta : "+event.wheelDelta);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show how 'ZoomMain` is consumed and where you are attaching `this.click` to click event handler. A brief of your plan is also appreciated :)

Comment: this would need hundreds lines... :/ it is really... loong... :/ (invitation to chat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if(typeof zoom === "function"){
    element.addEventListener("mousewheel",zoom,false);
}
else{
    alert(zoom);
}
```

if `zoom` is not a `function` probably that's a scope issue. Add all relevant code for more help.

PS: This is not a solution to the problem, but a solution to debug! If you are ok with developer tools, dubyg using that to see if `zoom` has a valid value.

> ```
> on click on my element, i try to add an event listener on mousewheel
> ```

Paste the click event handler and how you are binding `mousewheel` event handler inside click event handler. Also show where `zoom` is defined with relative to these.

http://jsfiddle.net/vucfrfke/3/

stupid issue, you redeclared `zoom`

Comment: i edited the zoom function
result is the alert... so typeof is not considered as function...

Comment: check the last request I made, add code including where you defined `zoom`, where you are binding `click` and how you are binding `mousewheel` inside `click` event handler.

Comment: Try to include JSLINT in your workflow to avoid stupid mistake grab our time.